# ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous' using DT with RF

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

I am trying to create a decision tree below is my code:

```
X=updated[['dayofthemonth','hour']]
y=updated['Encounters']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=80, shuffle=True)
gpc = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0).fit(X_train, y_train)
pre=gpc.predict(X_test)
gpc.score(X_test, y_test)
pre
```

I am trying to create a decision tree with it as well, so I updated the code as below:

```
X=updated[['dayofthemonth','hour']]
y=updated['Encounters']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=80, shuffle=True)
gpc = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0).fit(X_train, y_train)
pre=gpc.predict(X_test)
gpc.score(X_test, y_test)
pre
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, y)
```

but still getting the below errors:

```
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to clarify which type of machine learning problem you are trying to solve:

- **Categorical:** you are trying to predict one class (example: good,
  normal, bad)
- **Continuous/Regressor:** you are trying to predict one continuous value (example:
  house price)

So, what is your `y=updated['Encounters']`, categorical or continuous?

I will assume (watching the error) your desired output is continuous. So you are working with Regressor problem. In you random forest you used the model: `RandomForestRegressor()`, so, as the name say, it is a Random Forest used for Regression, so it will work.

But, when you are trying the decision tree, you applied the next model: DecisionTreeClassifier(). As you can see, now, you are implementing a Classifier model, which won't suit your problem. To solve it use the next code instead of `DecisionTreeClassifier()`:

```
clf = tree.DecisionTreeRegressor()
```